# Check if the keys exist in the other object

Tags: javascript

There are two objects `metadata` and `data`.

I have written the following code to find if `metadata` object keys exist in the `data` object.

I wonder if there is a shorthand of the following approach.

Here is the `data`

```
      "data": {
        "TripResults": {
          "Depth": [
            577,
            694,
            810
          ],
          "Speed": [
            150,
            150,
            150
          ],
          "Frequency": [
            3,
            3,
            3
          ]
        },
        // the following two lines are added
        "Trincot": true,
        "Belgium": 2019,  
        "SurveyResults": {
          "Depth": [
            577,
            694,
            810
          ],
          "Speed": [
            150,
            150,
            150
          ],
          "Frequency": [
            3,
            3,
            3
          ]
        },
        "LastCalling": {
          "Last_Calling_Duration": 5699,
          "Last_Calling_Date": 20180619
        }
      }
```

Here is the `metadata`

```
      "metaData": {
        "Depth": {
          "FieldName": "Depth"
        },
        "Time": {
          "FieldName": "Time"
        },
        "Frequency": {
          "FieldName": "Frequency"
        },
        "Speed": {
          "FieldName": "Speed"
        },
        "Last_Calling_Date": {
          "FieldName": "Last_Calling_Date"
        },
        "Last_Calling_Duration": {
          "FieldName": "Last_Calling_Duration"
        }
      }
```

Here is my naive approach:

```
var unitjson = {}
var tempArray = []
for (var key in metadata) {
    properties = []
    eachObject = []
    for (var datakey in data) {
        if (data[datakey] != null && data[datakey].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log("key exists");
            properties.push({ "propertyName": key, "values": data[datakey][key] })
            eachObject.push({ "name" : datakey, "properties": properties })
        }
    }
   tempArray.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eachObject)))
   unitjson["entities"] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tempArray))
}
```

Expected output is similar to follows:

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "name": "TripResults",
      "properties": [
        {
          "propertyName": "Depth",
          "values": [
            577,
            694,
            810
          ]
        },
        {
          "propertyName": "Speed",
          "values": [
            150,
            150,
            150
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "SurveyResults",
      "properties": [
        {
          "propertyName": "Depth",
          "values": [
            577,
            694,
            810
          ]
        },
        {
          "propertyName": "Speed",
          "values": [
            150,
            150,
            150
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "LastCalling",
      "properties": [
        {
          "propertyName": "Last_Calling_Date",
          "values": [
            20180619
          ]
        },
        {
          "propertyName": "Last_Calling_Duration",
          "values": [
            5699
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share some sample of data? you are searching only on the first level or want to do a deep search on the `data` object?

Comment: Deep Level as well.

Comment: We need sample input & output. Why do you reset `properties` in every iteration of the outer loop? Don't you need those results?

Comment: I have just added a sample for data and metadata

Comment: And now the required output for that sample input?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Now you overwrite `unitjson["entities"]` in each iteration. You're asking for a "shorthand", but if your code does not work, better state so.

Comment: I am actually adding the new object to the unitjson.

Comment: No, you are *overwriting* it (so only last result remains). Anyway, what is the expected output for your input?

Comment: After your latest update: `eachObject` is now getting the same properties multiple times. Is your code stable? We can help you with the right code, if you provide the expected output for the sample input you have given.

Comment: I have added expected output.

Comment: I have also added the missing line which is `tempArray`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195879/discussion-between-hotspring-and-trincot).

Comment: I am so completely confused by what it is you exactly want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first iterate the `data` instead of `metaData`, as the latter is just a set really,... there is no need to iterate it.

Then check for each nested object in `data` whether its property matches a meta data property, and if so create an entry for it.

I would suggest a *functional* approach which relies heavily on `Object.entries`, `filter` and `map`.

Here is how that would look:

```js
const data = {"TripResults": {"Depth": [577,694,810],"Speed": [150,150,150],"Frequency": [3,3,3]},"SurveyResults": {"Depth": [577,694,810],"Speed": [150,150,150],"Frequency": [3,3,3]},"LastCalling": {"Last_Calling_Duration": 5699,"Last_Calling_Date": 20180619}}
const metaData = {"Depth": { "FieldName": "Depth" },"Time": { "FieldName": "Time" },"Frequency": {"FieldName": "Frequency" },"Speed": { "FieldName": "Speed" },"Last_Calling_Date": { "FieldName": "Last_Calling_Date" },"Last_Calling_Duration": { "FieldName": "Last_Calling_Duration" }};

const entities = Object.entries(data).map(([name, properties]) => ({ 
    name, 
    properties: Object.entries(properties)
                .filter(([propertyName]) => propertyName in metaData)
                .map(([propertyName, value]) => ({
                        propertyName,
                        values: [].concat(value)
                }))
}));

console.log(entities);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @trincot, I wonder this approach also handles deep level mapping as well?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? You mean deep copy?

Comment: Can you edit your question and make sure it has an example that would require such "deep level mapping"?

Comment: I have seen that you bring the child object together, could you please check my output and your output? It is not actually matching. For example, under the `TripResults` object you put all `Depth` together even though one `Depth` object belongs to `TripResults` and other one belongs to `SurveyResults`. Feel free to change values of `Depth` to differentiate which `Depth` belongs to which parent object.

Comment: Could you check now?

Comment: It fails if the `data` does not have corresponding key in the `metadata` or also the `data` has key but values are `null`, it fails also. For example, if you assign `SurveyResults` to `null`, then it crashes. `"SurveyResults" : null`

Comment: Can you please edit your question and give an example where you have such conditions? I don't understand what the role of `metadata` is when you want *all* properties of `data` to be in the result, whether or not they exist in `metadata`.... I had understood that `metadata` would act as a filter. Apparently I misunderstood... I hope you can clarify these boundary conditions in your question.

Comment: I have updated the input by adding  `"Trincot": true,
"Belgium": 2019` which `Trincot` and `Belgium` keys do not exist in `metada`. If these key do not exist, then do not add or include into the result. Also even if it exists, only add the values which is numeric only, do not include anything like `string` on `boolean` values.

Comment: That is crucial information about your question. Please could you describe those rules in your question also? Comments are helpful, but the important information for interpreting the question should be present in the question itself.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how these new keys relate to `metadata`, as there the properties are about what is in the data *one level deeper*, like for instance `depth`. But you have added data properties at one higher level. I am totally confused now about what you want. It is really important to describe this in detail in the question.

Comment: I just want to map the data with metadata where the data value(s) is numeric only and also not null.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you do like I asked above? It really is not clear what you want. Those props are at a different level!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195972/discussion-between-hotspring-and-trincot).

Comment: please find the deep level question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56925151/deep-level-mapping-dealing-with-object-and-array-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment100392253_56925151

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach. Maybe not quite the shorthand you were hoping for.

```
const getEntities = (metadata, data) => Object.keys(data).map((dataKey) => {

    const dataEntity = data[dataKey];

    return {
        name: dataKey,
        properties: Object.keys(metadata).reduce((result, metadataKey) => {
            if (dataEntity[metadataKey] != null && dataEntity.hasOwnProperty(metadataKey)) {
                result.push({
                    propertyName: metadataKey,
                    values: dataEntity[metadataKey]
                })
            } // implied else... skip it cuss the prop doesn't match

            return result;
        }, [])
    };
});
```